# Content breaks when zoomed in on 100% Viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently making a simple landing page with Bootstrap. My Jumbotron is set to 100VH.

When testing yesterday I noticed the content inside of my Jumbotron breaks when the browser is zoomed in beyond 100%.

**Example of what is happening here**(Zoom IN): https://jsfiddle.net/y8dnbz3t/

---

**The Code:**
*CSS*

```
*{margin: 0;}

.jumbotron {position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;}

/* Div that breaks */

.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Content after 100VH */

.after {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**What I tried:**

I attempted setting the height of the 'Box' to auto. Didn't help.

I do not anticipate that many people zoom in or out.. but this is part of the development process and a bug I'd like to know how to fix.. and what causes it.

Comment: It's gotta be your "vh" that's breaking it.  Is there a reason you are using that?

Comment: To be honest.. I just like the effect it has and that it adjust to any screen. I guess this is one of those situations where I have to compromise?

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks'? I don't see an obvious problem unless you mean the line breaking of the text

Answer (score 2):

**How I somewhat Solved it:**

I simply changed the height of the Jumbotron from

**'height: 100vh'**

to

**'min-height: 100vh;'**

It does not keep the box element at the middle of the div as it should. But, it does solve the simple breaking issue that was occurring before.

I will try and add some transform:translate properties and see if I can get it to center properly this way.

Answer (score 0):

try changing .box class height to 50%

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I gave this a try.. and did not seem to fix the problem. I appreciate that answer.

Comment: what do you mean by break? is it the box go beyond footer? or the text inside the box overflow and not expanding with box ?

Comment: Yes, the box is overflowing it's parent container in this case.. the **Jumbotron** - excuse me for not making it clearer @Tengku